# SQL Server library not registered. (exception from hresult: 0x8002801d (type_e_libnotregistered))

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Trying to open my stored procedure through new query window in SQL Server 2012 but I get an error:

> Library not registered. (exception from hresult: 0x8002801d (type_e_libnotregistered))

Error screenshot:

[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3P0AV.png)

I tried to solve through below given solution on by Microsoft but still its not working.

https://support.microsoft.com/gl-es/help/2849799/library-not-registered-error-message-when-you-open-a-new-query-window

Please help me out

Comment: Check this out https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/be5ddbb6-6cf1-4dc9-af6f-8838274da585/ssms-typeelibnotregistered?forum=sqlexpress

Comment: It's the same thing I tried for the link which I have mentioned

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. I repaired the SQL Server from 'SQL Server Installation Center' and restarted and It worked.